# what is the keyboard shortcut for switching to subscript or superscript while using libre office

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I just want to know how to switch to superscript or subscript while using libre office as many of my documents are chemistry and physics based which require a lot of subscript and superscript to write molecular formulae and physical formulae. coming to the point, can I get a keyboard short cut for superscript or subscript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>   Superscript

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>   Subscript

<sup>LibreOffice Writer Help</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + Shift + P - Superscript

Ctrl + Shift + B - Subscript